# Modifying core data entity contents cause malfunction

Tags: ios, core-data, plist

My ios app has two entities called `Scout` and `MeritBadge`. The content of the `MeritBadge` is read and stored from a plist file. `AppDelegate` checks a flag that indicates the plist file version and if theres a newer version with more entries added to it, it removes all entries in the `MeritBadge` entity and re-add by reading the plist.

I added an extra entry to the plist and when I read the `MeritBadge` entity, I get the newly added entry.

But if I read the db with `ScoutMeritBadge` as the entity name, I get all badges except the newly added badge.

Does this mean that I need to re-build the DB if I add a new entry to the `MeritBadge` entity from the plist?

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: As far as building the app goes, every time you add/modify an entity you need to do a clean and have a fresh build. Maybe the same rules apply.

Comment: This only changes the entries in the MeritBadge table. Does not modify the table structure.